# Drawing numbers into a panel?

Tags: android, opengl-es, canvas, drawing

I was wondering if there was already a component available which the user could use the touchscreen to draw numbers into. If not, I was considering an openGL panel which their input would draw onto, and then I'd need some algorithm to interpret the drawing and parse it to a number.

Obviously, I'd prefer a component already exist, but am always up for a coding challenge :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An OpenGL component to display the strokes onto the screen should be relatively straightforward.  The handwriting recognition won't be, you should probably try to reuse some existing handwriting recognition software, which you may have to port to Android (note that this is NOT "parsing" and also that recognition from pen input where the order and continuity of the strokes are known should be much more accurate than OCRing the ink-ed image)

Comment: Ben, thanks for the info.  Do you know of any open source OCR algorithms (even for just numbers, as that's all I care about for now).  I agree that the OpenGL drawing part should be straightforward, and that OCR is where the challenge will lie.

Comment: Maybe CellWriter http://www.linux.com/archive/feed/120867?  OCR is what you don't want, you want something that processes stroke data, it will be much more accurate since it knows which dots are connected and which just happen to be adjacent.

Comment: Ben, my original idea when thinking of creating my own algorithm was to go stroke-based.  I think I'll investigate CellWriter, and post another comment if I get anywhere with it.  Thanks again for your suggestions!

Comment: My guess is that if you develop an OpenGL-based interface that the CellWriter author would be interested.  Good luck with that, it sounds like a very useful sort of thing tohave.

Answer (score 0):

Built-in Android keyboard?
Or I didn't understand a question?

Comment: didn't understand (maybe poorly worded).

I'm looking for a panel which the user could draw into to input numbers, rather than the keyboard.  This is similar to this: http://electricpocket.com/bugme-palm/bugme-mtg-sm.gif
(where you write/draw to the screen)

Answer (score 0):

As of right now, an existing paint component does not exist.